# ansible playbook public keys issue

Tags: ssh, key, ansible

I've got this basic playbook that appends all the public keys located in the public_keys folder to the user's folder in .ssh/authorized_keys:

```
- hosts: default

vars:
  user: user1

tasks:
- name: Set up authorized_keys for the user
  authorized_key: user={{ user }} key="{{ item }}"
  with_fileglob:
  - public_keys/*.pub
```

when I run it on ansible it gives me this error and I'm pretty much stuck with it:

```
TASK [Set up authorized_keys for the user] ************************
failed: [default] => (item=/Users/trax/Git/ansible-keys/public_keys/test.pub) => {"failed": true, "item": "/Users/trax/Git/ansible-keys/public_keys/test.pub", "msg": "invalid key specified: /Users/trax/Git/ansible-keys/public_keys/test.pub"}
```

The public key file is perfectly valid as I'm currently using it and it works perfectly. It has no comments in it, I will actually paste it here so you can see it:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC4e+RLnQAqo3azuFzbynD9n6L7Qc2NjEwNLQRqKOd17532rHAhGOxz9ZV7ca5J6y9Z8QyV2EP9oXXpXd7I9oG1ybiU2cOmMQ7mIMFnMgy90dgVmF4X4Rj3fPch271TIQhvBH36L1eagk98Tlj32zepHNmC7ECFiAUihxXsuGAcFK4l9Y3s0HZe913E1ewUxXjUZAaqmzEQwW621hWDDTU1zUCnPPqEe6DFy6PUP8YL8mLbbKuSL2W6bD7rzm1axZANvoYeD5egvzwSMeZ8f+XF3MbuyhiJhGEFjwDfDkibP4bwQqZm5IdI1c0Ot2X67OHFsHx04gbs6ZzBkD39Z6Jr trax@M.local
```

Any advise? Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the keyfiles are local to the control machine, it's easy to use a [file lookup](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#intro-to-lookups-getting-file-contents) to get the key content, eg:

```
- hosts: default
  tasks:
  - authorized_key:
      user: '{{ user }}'
      key: '{{ lookup('file', item) }}'
    with_fileglob: public_keys/*.pub
```

Answer (score 4):

The argument to the `key` parameter needs to be a *key* (not a path to the file, but the actual *contents*) or a *url*.  From the documentation:

> `key`  The SSH public key(s), as a string or (since 1.9) url (https://github.com/username.keys)

So you can add a task that will read keys into a registered variable, and then loop over that to install the keys:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: read keys

      # This needs to run on localhost, because that's where
      # the keys are stored.
      delegate_to: localhost

      command: cat {{item}}

      # Register the results of this task in a variable called
      # "keys"
      register: keys

      with_fileglob:
        - "public-keys/*.pub"

    - name: show what was stored in the keys variable
      debug:
        var: keys

    - authorized_key:
        user: fedora
        key: "{{item.stdout}}"
      with_items: "{{keys.results}}"
```

See the [Ansible documentation on using register with
loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop)
for details.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of these are old, I have an updated version that works for me.

```yaml
      - name: Set authorized key taken from file
        authorized_key:
          user: yourtargetusername
          state: present
          key: "{{ lookup('file', 'yourtargetkey.pub') }}"
```